# ZFS compressed and deduped filesystem on file

Tags: filesystems, compression, zfs, deduplication, squashfs

I can create `squashed` filesystems with `mksquashfs` in this way:

```
mksquashfs dir-1 dir-2 ... dir-n filesystem-on-file.squash -comp xz -Xbcj x86 -Xdict-size 1048576 -b 1024k
```

`mksquashfs` provides compression and deduplication of data but is read-only. Now I would like to create a few test filesystems with `ZFS` with both deduplication and compression enabled.

What is the equivalent command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will create a 100 MB file on /tmp then a zpool and zfs file system on it with both compression and deduplication enabled:

```
cd /tmp
dd if=/dev/zero of=zfile bs=1024k count=100
zpool create -O dedup=on -O compress=on filepool /tmp/zfile
```

The file system is mounted on /filepool and unlike squashfs is writable.

Just copy your files and directories in it and use `zpool list filepool` to get usage (ALLOC/FREE/CAP) and deduplication ratio (DEDUP).

eg.

```
# zpool list filepool
NAME       SIZE  ALLOC   FREE    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
filepool  95,5M  1,50M  94,0M     1%  2.99x  ONLINE  -
```

To see the compression ratio, use the `zfs get compressratio` command:

```
# zfs get compressratio filepool   
NAME      PROPERTY       VALUE  SOURCE
filepool  compressratio  1.37x  -
```

You can experiment with the various compression algorithms by specifying a non default one while creating the pool, eg.:

```
zpool create -O dedup=on -O compress=gzip-9 filepool /tmp/zfile
```

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. At the end I created the filesystem with these options: `zpool create -O dedup=sha256 -O checksum=sha256 -O compress=gzip-9 filepool /tmp/zfile` because I wanted better compression/deduplication. However `mksquashfs` seems to be much better for permanent archiving, probably because of LZMA2 compression.